# Java: while record exists = Keep adding number to the end of record

Tags: java, sql, while-loop

Basically I am adding a record to database: title and description.
I want to make it so if value of title already exists - add (1) or (2) to the end to make it distinguishable. I wrote this function:

```
public boolean existCheck(int userId, String title){
    String Validate = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM memories WHERE userid='"+userId+"' AND title='"+title+"'";
    int cnt = 0;
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        rs = st.executeQuery(Validate);
        if(rs.next()){
           cnt = rs.getInt(1);
           System.out.println(cnt);
           if(cnt != 0){

               result = true;
           }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return result;
}
```

It counts how many entries exist with that userID and Title. If not 0 then it exists and returns true that it exists.

This code adds record to database.

```
if(existCheck(userId, title) == true){
    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO memories (userid, title, description) VALUES ('"+userId+"', '"+title+"(1)', '"+desc+"')");
}
else{
    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO memories (userid, title, description) VALUES ('"+userId+"', '"+title+"', '"+desc+"')");    
}
```

But flaw in this code is that if title(1) already exists, it will add another title(1) again.
Of course I could make lots of if statements but I am sure I can do it with lesser lines using while loop.

I don't know how to use it in this case though, I don't want server to fall into infinite loop.

How do I apply while() loop to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `existCheck` should return the count instead of a boolean.

Then you can do something like :

```
int index = existCheck(userId, title);
if(index > 0){
      st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO memories (userid, title, description) VALUES ('"+userId+"', '"+title+index+"', '"+desc+"')");
} else{
      st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO memories (userid, title, description) VALUES ('"+userId+"', '"+title+"', '"+desc+"')");    
}
```

The first record entered would have `title`, the second `title+"1"`, the third `title+"2"`, and so on...

Of course, you'll also have to change the WHERE clause in `existCheck` to account for the different titles :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM memories WHERE userid='"+userId+"' AND title LIKE '"+title+"'%"
```

And while not entirely related to what you where asking, I strongly suggest that you use prepared statements instead of static statements (in which the parameter values are part of the SQL String). It would be much safer.

Comment: @arleitiss Read about SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

You should change `existCheck` to look for the title fuzzily, instead of:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM memories WHERE userid='"+userId+"' AND title='"+title+"'"
```

which looks for an exact title match, use

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM memories WHERE userid='"+userId+"' AND title LIKE '"+title+"%'"
```

Which will look for a title that starts with `title`.

Or, so that titles that start like a previous one aren't matched, you could also use:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM memories WHERE userid='"+userId+"' AND ( title='"+title+"' OR title LIKE '"+title+"(%)' )"
```

Note `%` will match anything in parentheses, so `title(soemthing)` would also match.

If you're using MySQL [you can use regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html), I'm not sure about other database servers.

---

As for avoiding repeated insertions of *title(1)*, you'll need to know the amount of titles that match your criteria, so just return the `COUNT`:

```
public int existCount(int userId, String title){
    String Validate = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM memories WHERE userid='"+userId+"' AND ( title='"+title+"' OR title LIKE '"+title+"(%)' )";
    int cnt = 0;
    try{
        rs = st.executeQuery(Validate);
        if(rs.next()){
           cnt = rs.getInt(1);
           System.out.println(cnt);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cnt;
}
// ...
final int count = existCount(userId, title);
if(count > 0){
    final String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO memories (userid, title, description) VALUES ('%d', '%s(%d)', '%s')", userId, title, count, desc);
    st.executeUpdate(sql);
}
else{
    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO memories (userid, title, description) VALUES ('"+userId+"', '"+title+"', '"+desc+"')");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In the exisTCheck() function, I will advice you to return the number instead of boolean. The return number will be number appended with the title. Say if you find only title in DB, then return 0. If you find title(1) then with string split get the number and return it. 

 While you are calling existCheck() function to check whether it is present or not, rather then true or false you will get counter. You just need to increment that counter with new value according to your requirement and modify your query. 


The abstract idea is like this....

Function int existCheck()enter code here
{
// Get the data from the db
// Split the string with title 
//if after title no string then return 0
//else return your number

}
// call to existCheck()
int count = existCheck();
//Modify your query with 
  st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO memories (userid, title, description) VALUES ('"+userId+"', '"+title+"count', '"+desc+"')");
```